# Can't got the token from the hearders

Tags: jwt

I do can log in, create the token and see it from the headers when I send the request post

```
router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
    const email = req.body.email
    const password = req.body.password
    connection.query( 
        `SELECT * FROM ETB.users WHERE email = ?;`, email,
        (err, result) => {
            console.log(result[0]);

            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).send(err)
              } else if (!result[0]){ 

                return res.status(409).send('Unknown user') 
              } 

          // check password
            const passwordIsValid = bcrypt.compareSync(password, result[0].password);
            console.log(passwordIsValid); 

            if(!passwordIsValid){
                console.log('wrong password');

                return res.status(401).send({ auth: false, token: null })
            }

          // Token creation 
          console.log('1', result[0].id);
          const token = jwt.sign(
            {id : result[0].id, email: result[0].email, type : result[0].type},  
            secret, 
            {
              expiresIn: '24h'
            },
            { algorithm: 'RS256' }
          );
            console.log(token);

            res.header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "x-access-token") 
            console.log(res.header());

            res.set("x-access-token", token); 
            res.status(200).send({ auth: true })

            connection.query(`UPDATE ETB.users SET last_login = now() WHERE id = '${result[0].id}'` )

    }); 
})
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18fUD.png)

However, when I tried to get a "logged" route; I keep on getting the "Acess Denied" and the token doesn't appears in the headers

```
router.get('/secret-route', userMiddleware.isLoggedIn, (req, res, next) => {
  res.json({
    posts: {
     title: "my first post",
      description: 'blabla'
    }
  }); 



});
```

Middleware

```
  isLoggedIn: (req, res, next) => {

      const token = req.header('x-access-token')
      if (!token) return res.status(401).send('Acess Denied');

      try {
        const verified = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
        req.user = verified;
      } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).send('Invalid Token')
      } 

   next();  
  }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aioPE.png)
 Thanks you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Postman itself does not maintain the headers. You have to copy and paste the token you received in the header inside an environment variable so that it's available to every request you make.

Refer to this [link](https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/getting-started/postman-collections) to learn how to add a header as an environment variable in Postman.

Another workaround is copying and pasting it to the 'x-access-token' header inside every request you make, but the first option is way better.